# Prompt asking for password then redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, database, passwords

I'm very new to PHP and JavaScript and I'm stuck. I spent a good 7 hours so far trying to figure this one out but I just do not know what or how to do it. So in my application, when you try to add a new row to my table, I have a html form to get the data. When you enter the data into the form, and press submit, it prompts for a password, and if the correct password is put in, it submits the form. It work just as I wanted it, here is what I have:

```
<button onclick="password()" type="button">Create New Hero</button>
    <div>
        <a id="discl">*-Required Fields</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function password(){
            var password = prompt("Please Enter the Admin Password");
            if(password != "shaun"){
                alert("Wrong Password");
            }
            else{
                if(validation()){
                document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
                }
                else{
                    alert("One or more required fields were left empty, or tried to use <script>");
                }
            }
        }
        function validation(){
            var f = document.getElementById("f_name").value;
            var l = document.getElementById("l_name").value;
            var d = document.getElementById("dob").value;
            var a = document.getElementById("alias").value;
            if(f == "" || l == "" || d == "" || f.includes("<script>") || l.includes("<script>") || a.includes("<script>")){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Now I also have an edit and delete on my table. My problem is that with edit and delete, they are in  tags with an href, and they are not buttons. This is how they originally looked when it worked without asking for a password:

```
               echo "<a href='./edit.php?id={$row['id']}'>edit</a>";
```

So based on which row of the table it was, where you clicked edit or delete, based on the row's id from the database, it would edit or delete that table. Now my problem is I don't know how to properly set up the function so it asks for the password and redirect to the right url. This is what I have right now:

```
           foreach($results as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$row['first_name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['last_name']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['date_of_birth']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['alias']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['active']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['hero']}</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a href='./edit.php?id={$row['id']}'>edit</a>";
            echo " | ";
            echo "<a  href='javascript: password()'>delete</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function password(){
            var password = prompt("Please Enter the Admin Password");
            if(password != "shaun"){
                alert("Wrong Password");
            }
            else{
                window.location.replace("./delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The problem with this is that no matter which delete I click on on my table, it always deletes the last one, because the ID it's getting out after the url is the last available ID from my database. I'm not sure if I'm just missing something small, or I'm completely on the wrong path but any help would be appreciated because I'm very lost. Thank you

Comment: Do you really validate the password in Javascript - which has the password hardcoded in it?

Comment: You do know that the password can easily be copied from the page via Ctrl + U on chrome.

Comment: `if(password != "shaun")` in JS - just love it!

Comment: Side note: I don't see `password_verify()` anywhere so this to me, suggests you're storing passwords as plain text which you shouldn't.

Comment: @mitkosoft Yes I know this is not secure, and not how password or login should be handled, but it is just for a small project. And I do pass $row['id'] in my password() function in the redirect, but as I said, that value is always the last id and it does not respond to which row of the table I clicked delete

Comment: `$row['id']` contains always the last ID from your PHP loop. You need to pass it within `password()` function during the loop itself and then to add it into `location.replace`.

Comment: Is this eventually going live or it's just for fun or educational purposes? If it's eventually going live, you might have a hard time implementing that code if/when you will store password hashes properly and to verify them with `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will not comment on any security issues here, just the logic. You need to pass `$row['id']` during PHP loop to your JS `password()` function that you want to use afterwards:

```
<?php
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row['first_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['last_name']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['date_of_birth']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['alias']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['active']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['hero']}</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='./edit.php?id={$row['id']}'>edit</a>";
        echo " | ";
        echo "<a  href='javascript: password(".$row['id'].")'>delete</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function password(delId) {
        var password = prompt("Please Enter the Admin Password");
        if (password != "shaun") {
            alert("Wrong Password");
        } else {
            window.location.replace("./delete.php?id="+delId);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring the blatant security issue, I suggest this

```
<a href='#' class='edit'   data-id='<?= $row['id'] ?>'>edit</a> | 
<a href='#' class='delete' data-id='<?= $row['id'] ?>'>delete</a>
```

using

```
window.addEventListerner('load',function() {
  document.querySelector('table').addEventListerner('click',function(e) {
    e.preventdefault(); // stop the link
    const tgt = e.target, id = tgt.getAttribute("id");
    if (tgt.classList.contains("edit") {
      location = '/edit.php?id='+encodeURIComponent(id);
    }
    else if (tgt.classList.contains("delete") {
      let password = prompt("Please Enter the Admin Password");
      if (password === "shaun") {
        location.replace('/delete.php?id='+encodeURIComponent(id)=;
      }
      else {
        alert("Wrong Password");
      }
    }
  })    
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It is the target request, not the calling page which requires authentication, otherwise anybody could call the `./delete.php?...` url and delete a row in the database.

This is usually done by maintaining a session, which remembers a login of the user. The `delete.php` request can then check whether the user is already logged in / has admin privileges, or demand the password when necessary.